# Is it right that in LCR cicuit Power loss $=VI$ not equal to Power loss $= V²/R$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I had a doubt today (this is not my homework question, I made it up). Suppose in a LCR circuit at resonance we take out power loss as  $P=VI \cos\phi$ (power factor and $\cos\phi$ becomes 1) and in another condition when there is no resonance  we take out power loss as $P'= VI\cos\phi$ (and $\cos\phi = R/Z$) .....now if we divide $P/P'$ we get $R/Z$ as the result.

Now when we take different formulas for powerloss like in the resonance condition
$$P = V^2/ R $$
and in the non-resonance condition
as
$$P' =V^2R /Z^2$$
and divide
$$P/P' = R^2/Z^2$$
So why i am getting different results ...or is there any conceptual mistake in my question ....power dissipated in both way should be the same?
I think my understanding about this is wrong. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the I at resonance is larger than when out of resonance.